# YouTube video to text?

Tags: video, audio

What are free easy ways to convert a YT video (not mine) to text?
I can download YT videos, so the question is not limited to online tools, but can include desktop ones. Also maybe it makes sense to first convert a downloaded YT video to audio, and then convert audio to text, in this case this question extends to audio to text converters.

I'm looking for an option that is quick and produces decent results. If there are no such free options, then please recommend some paid ones.

Comment: Do you know any "slow and not so decent" existing products? ...your keyword is "speec to text" and i am not aware of any ready to use solutions at this time...

Answer (score 4):

These 3 solutions took me like 30 sec to find by googling. Please do your due diligence and put a minimum of effort into it before asking your question here. There appear to be many more of thoose solutions already available.

1.
if the video has subtitles you can go to http://downsub.com/ and just enter the youtube video there and download the subtitles

2.
if there are no subtitles you can go to the page http://www.360converter.com and enter the youtube video there, it will take some time(there is a queue) but it will convert the sound into text. Only working with a limited number of languages tho.

3.
third but not least, youtube itself gives you the option
[image]

Comment: ok... 30 sec + 45 sec watching the video :D